# how to set timeout in ngResource query method on runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have a service holding all my API endpoint connectors. Those endpoint connectors are ngResource objects.

In some of them I override default methods, such as `get` or `query` for example to add `responseTransformers`. I'd like to be able to set `timeout` property of `get` method to stop one request before sending another, but I want to do it not in my service, where I define all `$resource`s:

```
this.collections = $resource(BackendConfig.apiUrl + 'collections/:uid/', {}, {
    query: {
        isArray: false,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: myTimeoutPromise
    },
});
```

but on runtime, just before I do this

```
Resource.collections.query().then(function () {});
```

Analysing code I came into conclusion, that it is possible to override params (2nd parameter), but not actions (3rd).

I found possible (not yet implemented) solution: create new service holding all timeouts (let's say Interrupter), inject it with my Resource service where I need it and define timeout promises there. Is there more convenient solution?

Comment: "service" way described above works poorly because when promise is once resolved it seems to block the use of method at all.

Comment: That's because once the promise is resolved, it stays permanently in that state. Thus, `collections.query()` won't work because AngularJS keeps thinking it's timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your $resources do, but maybe you can chain your promises into a provider.

```
$http.get( SOME_URL_HERE ).
  then( function(response){
    /*Resolve the first promise then chain your other requests*/
    var promises = [ ];

    promises.push ( $http.get( OTHER_URL ) );
    promises.push ( $http.get( AGAIN_OTHER_URL ) );

    return $q.all( promises );
  })
  .then ( function( responses){
    /*This 'then' is of the chaining*/
    reponses[0].something /*response of the first promise*/
    reponses[1].something /*response of the second promise*/

  })
  .catch( function(error){
    console.log( error );
  });
```